# Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$. Show $0 \in \mathbb F$ is the only element : $\alpha v = 0 \in V, \alpha \in \mathbb F, v \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb F$. Show $0 \in \mathbb F$ is the only element : $\alpha v = 0 \in V, \alpha \in \mathbb F, v \neq 0$.

Is this statement true ?

I know in a field $\mathbb F$, $0$ is the only zero divisor.

Comment: You have to suppose $v\neq 0$.

Comment: Take $v \neq 0$ then $\alpha=1$

Comment: Are you scared of quantifiers?

Comment: I suppose that now.

Comment: What do you mean rlartiga ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha v = 0$ for $\alpha \in F$, $0 \ne v \in V$,  then we must have $\alpha = 0$, for if $\alpha \ne 0$, then $v = \alpha^{-1} \alpha v = \alpha^{-1} 0 = 0$, a contradiction.  So we must then have $\alpha = 0$, which shows $\alpha$ is unique.  In this sense scalar-vector multiplication has the "no zero divisors" property; $\alpha v = 0$ if and only if $\alpha = 0$ or $v = 0$.  Of course, if $v = 0$, then $\alpha v = 0$ for *any* $\alpha \in F$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you, Robert. I didn't knew we had to use contradiction in order to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose  $\;0\neq w\in\Bbb F\;$ is such that

$$\forall\,v\in V\;,\;\;0=w\cdot v\stackrel{\text{mult. by}\;w^{-1}}\implies 0=w^{-1}wv=1\cdot v=v$$

where we used associativity, inverse and etc. from the axioms.

The claim now follows if there exists $\;0\neq v\in V\;\ldots$